# Django Projects Working Fine; Reopened and Import Module Error

Tags: python, django

I've been working on a Django project, my first, with no issues. I closed the file and restarted the computer for software updates and I'm now receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute_manager
setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in setup_environ
    project_module = import_module(project_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Stentorian
```

The module name is the name of the project. I cannot figure out what could possibly be going wrong to cause this error. Any insight into the would be most appreciated.

Edit: here is the Python sys.path:

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-    py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv (seems like you're not, but did you forget about activating it)?  What is your directory structure relative to your manage.py? What is your django version? What is your PYTHONPATH? Could you get your sys.path ? (hack into your manage.py script to print it)

Comment: No virtualenv. Django 1.3.1. Not sure what the sys.path is not how to print it out. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I ran python manage.py shell within the project to find the sys.path but as soon as I ran it I received the same error: ImportError: No module named Stentorian. I apologize for the frustration but this has been maddening and I can't find a resource to resolve this.

Comment: What is your directory structure? Where is your manage.py relative to your project files? sys.path is the list of directory that python will search when you attempt an import. Add the following at the top of your manage.py: import sys; print sys.path
Run your script again; the path should be above the traceback.

Comment: Is the directory containing the Stentorian directory in this path?

Comment: Okay, I added import sys; print sys.path to the top of the manage.py file. The folder is there but I added it a few minutes ago with an append; still doesn't work and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this `Stentorian` project directory has an `__init__.py`. You can add the parent directory to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in `~/.bash_profile` on the Mac, or you could append the directory in the `manage.py` script. Having `.` and `..` on the PYTHONPATH is pretty customary, in your bash_profile:

```
 PYTHONPATH=.:..:/path/to/parent:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Or, in the manage.py script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
```